# How to customize Microsoft teams app header bar?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to add a hamburger button besides the brand logo icon in the app header bar.

Is this supported in Microsoft Teams app?

[image]

Here is an app has additional properties on the right side.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add a hamburger button besides the brand icon. We cannot alter the design specified by MS Teams

Comment: What about setting is Fullscreen to true and have my own header?

Comment: It is not possible to change the app header bar. However you can add the hamburger button inside the tab.

Comment: I notice some apps have addition items on the right side of the app bar. Is it possible to add additional item on the right side of the app header bar?

Comment: Could you please share screenshots of the same?

Comment: I added additional image in the question.

Comment: This pattern also exists in the shifts app. Can you share some insight how that works?

Comment: Shifts and Viva learning apps are 1st party apps developed my Microsoft. This feature is not available for 3rd party apps.